# err is blank but err.message exists on expressJS

Tags: javascript, express

In ExpressJS app final app.use which is using for error handling

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  console.log('as',typeof err);
  // res.render('error1', {
  //   message: err.message,
  //   error: {}
  // });
  res.json(err.message)
});
```

When I log err it print as {} ,but when I log err.message it show string like 'obj is not defined'. Why this happens and how I can see all the keys of err object like message .

Comment: Usually you should find the important properties of the error object in the API documentation of ExpressJS, or use a JS debugger to inspect the object at runtime. Of course you can always use JS itself to print all properties, but usually that's not the best way.

Comment: you may try logging just the err using console.log(err) or res.json(err.message)

Comment: Object.toString is not the same as JSON.stringify(Object). Object.toString often renders as {}

Comment: If you call `res.json(err)` it will encode your error using `JSON.stringify(err)`. Any properties inherited from the prototype will not be included.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if(err){
        res.json(err)
    }
    else{
        //err is {}
    }
});
```

If it is not error, then the `err` will be `null`.